# Does anyone know how to set a path in excel4node's wb.write() function?

Tags: node.js, excel4node

Below function is creating the excel file and saving it on my source folder.However i want to set a specific path where the file will only be saved on that specific path 
     wb.write(`${filename}.xlsx`)

Answer (score -2):

You can just add the path as a parameter:

ex.

```
  return wb.write(`./report/excelReports/report-${month}.xlsx`)
```